# IIS/web.config Redirect folder to another host but not its sub directoy

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I have a two servers, one is for development and the other is for production.

My local environment's database is often refreshed so that the data that appears on my local environment becomes an exact mirror of the production server. However the images which are referenced in that database are not because the image library is far too large.

Is it possible for me to redirect images to the images directory on the production server but exclude any subfolders within the directory from being redirected.

I need to be able to do this either using web.config or by IIS.

For example:

```
localhost/images/file.jpg | .gif | .png
```

to redirect to

```
productionserver/images/file.jpg | .gif | .png
```

but exclude

```
localhost/images/assets/
```

Comment: Possibly though I don't know how. I assume there is no option of moving those images into a subdirectory so that it can be overridden easily because it has no subfolders in it any more?

Comment: This would have been the ideal set up however I am dealing with a website that has a long lifespan and is very large so without changing all code I am unable to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to get your regex right:

```
<rules>
   <rule name="image redirect" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^images/([^/]*)$" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="productionserver/images/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working without it sending all of the images to the production server. So in the end I set up another instance of my local website in IIS and pointed the images directory to the production server and then pointed the assets directory to the cloned version of the website's assets directory - probably not the most efficient use of IIS but it's working with no problems.